# Relation defined by an equation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I would like to know if I got right this exercise.

Find the relation defined by $y^2=25-x^2$, where $x$ belongs to $D=\{0,3,4,5\}$.

I substituted the values in the set $D$ in $x$.

- For $x=0$, I got $y=\pm5$
- For $x=3$, I got $y=\pm4$
- For $x=4$, I got $y=\pm3$
- For $x=5$, I got $y=0$

So my relation is:

$R=\{(0,-5),(0,5),(3,-4),(3,4),(4,-3),(4,3),(5,0)\}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: thanks for ur help. :)